# Java Data read from a file only stores data within the try statement. Everywhere else returns "null" or "0."

Tags: java, methods, file-io, constructor, null

I'm working on a project that requires me to create a parameter constructor with one String parameter that splits information and assigns data variable to the split data.

Data File

```
Jan 3128 1.59 3421 1.79
Feb 3130 1.59 2822 1.79
Mar 3126 1.59 3210 1.79
Apr 3075 1.69 3143 1.79
May 3250 1.69 2538 1.79
Jun 3133 1.69 3458 1.79
Jul 3211 1.79 3135 1.89
Aug 2958 1.79 3620 1.89
Sep 2823 1.79 3714 1.89
Oct 2989 1.89 3689 1.99
Nov 3088 1.89 4163 1.99
Dec 2906 1.89 4314 1.99
```

Here's said constructor.

```
//Constructor

public SU2017Project_MonthlyTransaction (String[] split) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    try {
        Scanner st = new Scanner(file17);

           while (st.hasNextLine()) 
           { 
               split = st.nextLine().split(" ");
               String month = split[0];
               int M554_uCount = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
               double M554_uPrice = Double.parseDouble(split[2]);
                int M664_uCount = Integer.parseInt(split[3]);
                double M664_uPrice = Double.parseDouble(split[4]);
                System.out.println(month);
           }

           st.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

           System.out.println("File not found");

           System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Here's the code to write to a new file

```
//write to Sale_Summary_2017
public void writetoFile()
{
    try

    {

    String filename= "Sale_Summary_2017.txt";

        FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter(filename,true); 

        fwriter.write(Arrays.toString(month));//write the string to the file

        fwriter.close();

    }
        catch(IOException ioe)

    {
        System.err.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());

    }


public class SU2017Project_SaleReport
```

{

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{

    SU2017Project_MonthlyTransaction MT = new SU2017Project_MonthlyTransaction_(args);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(MT.month));

    MT.writetoFile();
}
```

The `"System.out.println(Arrays.toString(MT.month));"` is just a test output to see what my outputted variables would be. For the strings, I would get null. For the double and ints, I would get zero. Yet for some reason, the output statement I kept in my try statement "`System.out.println(month);`" was returning the values I had in the data file. Can anyone help me find out where I'm going wrong. I've been trying to figure out for days.

Comment: Your constructor makes no sense. It does not take a single String parameter but rather an array of String. It then ignores anything that might have been passed in. It has file I/O within it that does not look to belong within it (that code should go elsewhere, no?).

Comment: Where are you setting `MT.month`?  (Hint: not where you think you are.)

Comment: Instead perhaps (and I'm guessing since we don't have the actual requirements word-for-word), you should read in the file, get a line from each row of the file within a while loop, pass that single String into your constructor, split it and create your fields.

Comment: You also look to be creating a bunch of variables ***local*** to the constructor, don't appear to be assigning anything to instance fields confirming that yes, this is all very confused.

Comment: Suggestion: scrap this code as trust me, it's no good. Create a simple and pure POJO, one with the fields that are defined by each row of data in your text file. Give this POJO a constructor that takes a row String. Within that constructor simply split the String and **assign the results to appropriate instance fields** of your class. In your main method, create an `ArrayList<MyPojo>` of your type. Open the file, within main, read in each line of text from the file, create a new object of your type by passing in this line and add this to your ArrayList. Done.

Comment: Then later give your POJO a decent `public String toString()` method that displays the data that it holds, and at the end iterate through your List printing out each line of data.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not used to how constructors fully work. Yes you're right about passing the string into the constructor and splitting it or as I was told "Constructor pass a String as parameter, split information and assign to data members."

Comment: So again, do what I told you to do. Get all that file I/O crap out of your `SU2017Project_MonthlyTransaction` constructor. It does not belong there. All that this constructor should do is to be able to accept a String parameter (again ***not*** a String array as you're doing it), take that String and split it and then parse the array into fields. Your question suggests that you are unclear still on some of the very basics of Java, and you will want to review the appropriate tutorials before moving on.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll let you know how it goes.